# How many 5 digit numbers can be constructed using the following digits: 62664277?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 5 digit numbers can be constructed using the following digits: 62664277?

I tried to solve the problem this way:

If we have 8 digits (62664277) and need to create a 5 digit-number, we can write the number of 5 digit-numbers as $$n=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}{2!\cdot4!}$$ since we have 8 permutations but some of them are the same variation, thus dividing the number of permutations by $2!\cdot4!$.

Now this is wrong, but I don't understand why. In my textbook there is a formula: $$\frac{n!}{n_1!\cdot n_2!\cdot\ldots \cdot n_i!}.$$ Why doesn't this work in this case where we are choosing 5 digits out of 8?

Comment: Why $4!$ in denominator

Answer (score 4):

Your formula is the number of distinct numbers that can be created from *all* of those digits. If we only want five, we’re going to have to do casework.

The set of digits for this five digit number must look either like $\{w,w,x,y,z\}$, like $\{w,w,x,x,y\}$, or like $\{w,w,w,x,x\}$. For each of these cases, we can first count the number of ways to choose the digits, and then multiply by the number of ways to order them. This gives:

- $\{w,w,x,y,z\}$: $3\cdot\frac{5!}{2!\cdot1!\cdot1!\cdot1!}=180$.
- $\{w,w,x,x,y\}$: $6\cdot\frac{5!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot1!}=180$.
- $\{w,w,w,x,x\}$: $2\cdot\frac{5!}{3!\cdot2!}=20$.

This gives a total of $\boxed{380}$ numbers.

Comment: u missed some of cases i think - say 0 ws, xxyzz. In fact there are 3 sixes, 2 twos, 1 four, 2 seven. we need to pick 5 out of them.

Comment: @NascimentodeCos The case you mention is the same case as $\{w,w,x,y,y\}$. The number of occurrences of each digit should be already factored in.

Comment: understood. Thank you.